# New register Admob Ads does not display on app

Tags: android, admob, signed-apk

I have generated a new banner ads and interstitial ads on google admob but the ads don't display on app.

I find many way on google there are a few said that new generated ads need to wait at least 24 hours to appear on app but my ads has came up 3 days ago already its still not appear.

When i replaces the ads id with test ads id, the test ads came out on the app with no problem. What is the problem cause my ads id cannot be used?

Comment: create release build by sign and check

Comment: i done create the release and check the V1 and V2 signature to generated signed app but it still don't work.